# how to do ${bean.methodWithArg('${value}')} in el jsp

Tags: java, jsp, el

I want to fetch all the subjects and topics related to Subject from DB just like :

>   1- Java Basic // As Subject and topics below
>   - Variable
>   - Operators
>   - Java Statement
>   2- PHP Basic // As Subject and topics below
>   - Variable
>   - Operators
>   - Statement

in code it is :

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="com.super.db.dao.SuperBean" scope="page"></jsp:useBean>
<c:forEach items="${subjects}" var="subject">
    <li
       <c:catch>
        <c:choose>
             <c:when test="${subject.subjectId == param.subj_id}">
            <!-- Here I'm getting value of subject.subjectId in each Iteration and I need that *** -->
       </c:catch>><a href='/super-context/super-controller?action=view-content&subj_id=
            <c:out value="${subject.subjectId}"/>'>
            <c:out value="${subject.subjectName}" />
        </a></li>
        <ul class="pages">  <!-- *** Here that value in each Iteration as well So I'm trying just like below ${topicDAO.topicList('${subject.subjectId}')} -->                          
            <c:forEach items="${bean.topicList('${subject.subjectId}')}" var="topic">
                <li
                <c:catch>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${topic.topicId == param.topic_id}">
                    <c:out value=" class=\"selected\""/>
                    </c:when>
                </c:choose> 
                </c:catch>><a href='/super-context/super-controller?action=view--content&topic_id=
                    <c:out value="${topic.topicId}"/>'>
                    <c:out value="${topic.topicName}" />
                </a></li>
                </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</c:forEach>
```

I'm stuck in my code where I face scenario like :

```
${bean.methodWithArg('${value}')}
```

#### EDIT

```
bean.topicList(subjectId);
```

from above I want to get subjectId and use here :

```
public List<Topic> topicList(String subjectId) throws SQLException{
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        connection = DatabaseManager.initConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM topic WHERE subj_id = " + subjectId + " ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 0 , 30");// Here this ${bean.topicList('${subject.subjectId}')} subject ID is required.
       // System.out.println("ResultSet returned...");
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Topic topic = new Topic();
            topic.setTopicId(resultSet.getString(Constant.TOPIC_COL_ID));
            topic.setSubjectId(resultSet.getString(Constant.TOPIC_SUBJECT_COL_NAME));
            topic.setTopicName(resultSet.getString(Constant.TOPIC_COL_NAME));
            topics.add(topic);
        }
    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    }

    return topics;
}
```

when I use :

```
${topicDAO.topicList('subject.subjectId')}
```

I get

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'subject.subjectId' in where clause'
```

I could figure that out how to get the above code work. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: try `${bean.methodWithArg('value')}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case `value` is a known variable in expression language the current page (stored in page, request, session or application context), use it like this:

```
${bean.methodWithArg(value)}
```

If you're passing a concrete `String` "value", use it like this:

```
${bean.methodWithArg('value')}
```

By the way, the code above is supported by [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el.htm), it is not JSTL.

---

Not related to your original problem but you're misusing `PreparedStatement`. You should not append the parameters in the query, instead mark the parameters in the statement as `?` and then set the values for the parameters. Change the code to:

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM topic WHERE subj_id = ?"
    + " ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 0 , 30");
statement.setString(1, subjectId);
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: If if do as you suggested then I get exception, Please see Edit

Comment: You get what? Please do not post code in comments, instead edit your question and add the relevant code/messages there.

Comment: Okay now see latest _EDIT_ please

Comment: @user3310291 ok, seems that you haven't understood my answer. IF you're passing a String constant, use the latter. If you're passing a variable known in page, request, session or application context (stored as attribute), use the former.

Comment: @user3310291 you're welcome. Also, check the update on my answer.